# How to replace/update python-eggtrayicon in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, python

I've wrote a pygtk script using [python-eggtrayicon](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/python-eggtrayicon) but not available in Trusty.
However, I've this package installed in my Trusty, because I come from Saucy.
How can I replace it? 
Is it possible to build the package in my ppa, to distibute my work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Python_version), using appindicator.

Comment: yep, Unity made change to appindicator instead of system tray. This is most convenient solution.  Would you accept you own answer.